# calling variable from header file explicity

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have a c file and a header file. I wanted to use the variable explicity using C. How to use `extern` keyword for the case below :

glob.h

```
#ifndef GLOB_H
#define GLOB_H
static int a=10;
#endif
```

Main program

```
#include"glob.h"

int c = 20;

void loop()
{
  if(c>a)
  {
    Serial.printf("welcome");
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. If you can't even bother to look at the question preview before you post (caps lock, indentation), why should we spend our time looking at it and answering it? 2. What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: what problem are you getting? and c/c++?

Comment: You probably should have a look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the extern declaration to your main program

```
#include"glob.h"

int c = 20;
extern int a;

void loop()
{
  if(c>a)
  {
    Serial.printf("welcome");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`extern` is used to tell the compiler to not redefine a variable as it exists in another compiled object file and to not redefine it in the current object file but reference the existing variable in the other object file instead. In your code above you don't redefine your `a` variable in your main program so you don't need it as long as we're talking about the same compiled object file.